# List of Active Directory DNS servers IP addresses in an SSM document

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am converting my 0.11 code to 0.12. Most things seem to be working out well, but I am really lost on the SSM document.

In my 0.11 code, I had this code:

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "ssm_document" {
    name = "ssm_document_${terraform.workspace}${var.addomainsuffix}"
    document_type = "Command"
    content = <<DOC
    {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "description": "Automatic Domain Join Configuration",
        "runtimeConfig": {
            "aws:domainJoin": {
                "properties": {
                    "directoryId": "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.id}",
                    "directoryName": "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.name}",
                    "dnsIpAddresses": [
                        "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.dns_ip_addresses[0]}",
                        "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.dns_ip_addresses[1]}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DOC
    depends_on = ["aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab"]
}
```

This worked reasonably well. However, Terraform 0.12 does not accept this code, saying

> This value does not have any indices.

I have been trying to look up different solutions on the web, but I am encountering countless issues with datatypes. For example, one of the solutions I have seen proposes this:

```
"dnsIpAddresses": [
                    "${sort(aws_directory_service_directory.oit-microsoftad-lab.dns_ip_addresses)[0]}",
                    "${sort(aws_directory_service_directory.oit-microsoftad-lab.dns_ip_addresses)[1]}",
                ]
            }
```

and I am getting

> InvalidDocumentContent: JSON not well-formed

which is kinda weird to me, since if I am looking into trace log, I *seem* to be getting relatively correct values:

```
{"Content":"{\n    \"schemaVersion\": \"1.0\",\n    \"description\": \"Automatic Domain Join Configuration\",\n    \"runtimeConfig\": {\n        \"aws:domainJoin\": {\n            \"properties\": {\n                \"directoryId\": \"d-9967245377\",\n                \"directoryName\": \"012mig.lab\",\n                \"dnsIpAddresses\": [\n                    \"10.0.0.227\",\n
      \"10.0.7.103\",\n                ]\n            }\n        }\n    }\n}\n    \n","DocumentFormat":"JSON","DocumentType":"Command","Name":"ssm_document_012mig.lab"}
```

I have tried concat and list to put the values together, but then I am getting the datatype errors. Right now, it looks like I am going around in loops here.

Does anyone have any direction to give me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform 0.12 has stricter types than 0.11 and less automatic type coercion going on under the covers so here you're running into the fact that the output of the [`aws_directory_service_directory`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/directory_service_directory.html) resource's [`dns_ip_addresses` attribute](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/directory_service_directory.html#dns_ip_addresses) [isn't a list but a set](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/f354e8b455e37ae0bb87f16ab15093dccf263095/aws/resource_aws_directory_service_directory.go#L150-L155):

```golang
            "dns_ip_addresses": {
                Type:     schema.TypeSet,
                Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
                Set:      schema.HashString,
                Computed: true,
            },
```

[Set's can't be indexed directly](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#set-) and instead must first be converted to a list explicitly in 0.12.

As an example:

```
variable "example_list" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
}


output "list_first_element" {
  value = var.example_list[0]
}
```

Running `terraform apply` on this will output the following:

```
Outputs:

list_first_element = foo
```

However if we use a set variable instead:

```
variable "example_set" {
  type = set(string)
  default = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
}

output "set_first_element" {
  value = var.example_set[0]
}
```

Then attempting to run `terraform apply` will throw the following error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 22, in output "set_foo":
  22:   value = var.example_set[0]

This value does not have any indices.
```

If we convert the set variable into a list with [`tolist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html) first then it works:

```
variable "example_set" {
  type = set(string)
  default = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
}

output "set_first_element" {
  value = tolist(var.example_set)[0]
}
```

```
Outputs:

set_first_element = bar
```

Note that sets may have different ordering to what you may expect (in this case it is ordered alphabetically rather than as declared). In your case this isn't an issue but it's worth thinking about when indexing an expecting the elements to be in the order you declared them.

Another possible option here, instead of building the JSON output from the set or list of outputs, you could just directly encode the `dns_ip_addresses` attribute as JSON with the [`jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
variable "example_set" {
  type = set(string)
  default = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
}

output "set_first_element" {
  value = jsonencode(var.example_set)
}
```

Which outputs the following after running `terraform apply`:

```
Outputs:

set_first_element = ["bar","foo"]
```

So for your specific example we would want to do something like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "ssm_document" {
    name = "ssm_document_${terraform.workspace}${var.addomainsuffix}"
    document_type = "Command"
    content = <<DOC
    {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "description": "Automatic Domain Join Configuration",
        "runtimeConfig": {
            "aws:domainJoin": {
                "properties": {
                    "directoryId": "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.id}",
                    "directoryName": "${aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.name}",
                    "dnsIpAddresses": ${jsonencode(aws_directory_service_directory.microsoftad-lab.dns_ip_addresses)}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DOC
}
```

Note that I also removed the unnecessary `depends_on`. If a resource has interpolation in from another resource then Terraform will automatically understand that the interpolated resource needs to be created before the one referencing it.

The [resource dependencies documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-dependencies) goes into this in more detail:

> Most resource dependencies are handled automatically. Terraform
> analyses any expressions within a resource block to find references to
> other objects, and treats those references as implicit ordering
> requirements when creating, updating, or destroying resources. Since
> most resources with behavioral dependencies on other resources also
> refer to those resources' data, it's usually not necessary to manually
> specify dependencies between resources.
>
> However, some dependencies cannot be recognized implicitly in
> configuration. For example, if Terraform must manage access control
> policies and take actions that require those policies to be present,
> there is a hidden dependency between the access policy and a resource
> whose creation depends on it. In these rare cases, the `depends_on`
> meta-argument can explicitly specify a dependency.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it right up. I think I should invest more time into reading Terraform documentation, since I potentially could have found the answer myself if I would have spent some more time reading different data types.

I did try wrapping the variables in list(), but not tolist(), and it looks like that was one of my mistakes.

Thank you.